# Xamarin Forms - passing value from Xaml.cs to custom renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I have a page called MapPage.Xaml.cs and on that page's constructor I have an argument called `bool isFireHazard`. In my Custom Renderer `CustomMapRenderer.cs` in my Android project, I want to check that `boolean` to see whether it is true.

How do I reference this boolean from my custom renderer?

Comment: Where are you use CustomMapRenderer - before MapPage or on this page?

Comment: You will have to show some more code if you want us to be able to help you

Answer (score 3):

You need to store isFireHazard passed to constructor in CustomMap object member. Then in CustomMapRenderer you can access it as

```
protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<xxx> e)
    {
       base.OnElementChanged(e);

       if (e.NewElement != null)
       {
          var formsMap = (CusomMap)e.NewElement;
          if(formsMap.isFireHazard)
          {
          }
       }
    }
```